# Using clickable initial configuration option in dropzone

Tags: reactjs, redux, dropzone.js

I want to use clickable option in dropzone. I am using dropzone component as given on this [link.](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component)

I am rendering the dropzone with following configuration.

```
let djsConfig = {
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,application/pdf,application/txt',
  clickable: false,
  autoProcessQueue: false,
};
```

Below code is return statement of render method which generates view.

```
return(
<div>
<DropzoneComponent
          config={componentConfig}
          eventHandlers={eventHandlers}
          djsConfig={djsConfig}
    />
<DropDownMenu
           value={this.state.value}
           onChange={this.handleChange} 
          >
            <MenuItem value={0} primaryText="Select Document Type" />
            <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Pan Card" />
            <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Votar Id" />
            <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Certificate" />
            <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Passports" />
          </DropDownMenu>
</div>
);
```

I want to use handleChange method as described in comment.

```
handleChange = (event, index, value) => {
/*
 When dropdown value is 0 then it dropzone should not be clickable and 
 and after dropdown have some value > 0, dropzone should be clickable.
*/
this.setState({ value });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone components can be enabled and disabled programmatically.

Check the bottom section of the [Dropzone Methods Documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods) to find the section about enable/disable.

In your `handleChange` function simply call `dropzoneComponent.enable()` or `dropzoneComponent.disable()` based on the new value of your dropdown menu.